# Sluggish refreshing of jQuery Mobile radio button?

Tags: jquery-mobile

jQuery 1.7.1 and jQuery Mobile 1.1.0RC1

Hello, I have a JQM radio button on my site and am programmatically changing its value based on a condition I'm checking on pageshow.  Everything works fine, but it isn't happening very "smoothly," by which I mean that it is very visible to the user when it changes i.e. it's in its original state for half a second or so and then switches.  Maybe I'm being a little picky, but I'd like the switch to be transparent to the user.  I'm still trying to understand the various JQM "page*" events and thought if I did it on pagebeforeshow or pagebeforecreate it would make that happen, but that is not the case.

I've tried to do a jsFiddle for it (my first time), it's happening pretty instantaneously there (maybe something to do with my selection of onDomReady in the options?) but should give you an idea of what I'm talking about ... on my site the selection is very obviously in the Off state for a moment when the page loads and then switches over to On.  It's not really a big deal, I'm asking more to help my understanding of the various page* events.

http://jsfiddle.net/pdjeU/

More info:

The web app is basically a document browser, constructed like so:  the index.html files contains a list of the documents, or rather a list of links to the TOCs of the available documents.  Each of these TOCs contains links to the sections of the actual document.

The code is as follows ... It's probably riddled with bad style since I'm a beginner.  The code for my radio button issue is in lines 30-39 of custom2.js and 23-28 of ch2-sec1.html.  Also, note that the `console.log($("link[href$='styleDay.css']").length);` line of code in custom2.js prints out "2" when the stylesheet ends with styleDay.css, and I have no idea why (I expect it to be "1").  My main problem, though, is that there is a noticeable lag when browsing through the content files (e.g. ch2-sec1.html as shown below) and the code flips the radio button to "Day Mode" when the condition is true ... can't this be coded so that it's already flipped by the time the page becomes visible?

root/index.html ...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/styleNight.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/jquery.mobile.simpledialog.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.mobile.simpledialog2.min.js"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/custom2.js"> </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="main">
            <div data-role="header">
                <div style="float:left; width:20%">
                    <a id="openOptions" href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear">Settings</a>
                </div>
                <div style="float:left; width:60%; text-align:center; padding-top:5px">
                    <h2>DOCUMENT LIST</h2>
                </div>
                <div style="float:left; width:20%">
                    <a id="openSearch" href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="right">Search</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content" style="clear:both">
                <div data-role="controlgroup">
                    <a href="doc1-toc.html">Document 1</a>
                    <a href="doc2-toc.html">Document 2</a>
                    <a href="doc3-toc.html">Document 3</a>
                    <a href="doc4-toc.html">Document 4</a>
                    <a href="doc5-toc.html">Document 5</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /page -->
    </body>
</head>
```

root/doc1-toc.html ...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/ftidStyleNight.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/custom2.js"> </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" data-theme="b">
            <div data-role="header" style="position:relative">
                <div style="float:left"><a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="home">Home</a></div>
                <h1>Document 1 TOC</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <div data-role="collapsible-set">
                    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
                        <h3>
                            <font color="white">Chapter 1</font>
                        </h3>
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c">
                            <li><a href="HTML/ch1-sec1.html">Chapter 1 Section 1</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
                        <h3>
                            <font color="white">Chapter 2</font>
                        </h3>
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c">
                            <li><a href="HTML/ch2-sec1.html">Chapter 2 Section 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="HTML/ch2-sec2.html">Chapter 2 Section 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="HTML/ch2-sec3.html">Chapter 2 Section 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="HTML/ch2-sec4.html">Chapter 2 Section 4</a></li>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

root/HTML/ch2-sec1.html ...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title> </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Style/styleNight.css"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/custom1.js"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/custom2.js"> </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="doc1-ch2-sec1">
            <div id="header" data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
                <div id="optionsDiv">
                    <div style="float:left; width:25%; text-align:left">
                        <a href="../index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-theme="b">Home</a>
                        <a href="ch2-sec1.html" id="previous" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-theme="b">Previous</a>
                    </div>
                    <div style="float:left; width:50%">
                        <div class="containing-element">
                            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" id="day-night">
                                <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="day" value="../Style/styleDay.css" data-theme="b"/>
                                <label for="day">Day Mode</label>
                                <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="night" value="../Style/styleNight.css" checked="checked" data-theme="b"/>
                                <label for="night">Night Mode</label>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="float:left; width:25%; text-align:right">
                        <a href="../doc1-toc.html" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-u" data-theme="b">TOC</a>
                        <a href="ch2-sec3.html" id="next" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r">Next</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Main content from legacy data source ->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

root/JS/custom2.js ...

```js
$("#main").live("pageinit",function(){
      $('<div>').simpledialog2({
        mode: 'blank',
        animate:false,
        top:10,
        left:10,
        themeDialog:'a',
        headerText: false,
        headerClose: false,
        blankContent : 
          "<span>Active Checklists:&nbsp;</span><select name='slider' id='flip-b' data-role='slider' data-mini='true' data-theme='a'><option value='off'>Off</option><option value='on'>On</option></select>"+
      "<a rel='close' data-role='button' data-theme='b' style='color:white' href='#'>Cancel</a>"
      });
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#openSearch', function() {
      $('<div>').simpledialog2({
        mode: 'blank',
        themeDialog:'a',
        animate:false,
        top:10,
        left:'60%',
        headerText: false,
        headerClose: false,
        blankContent : 
          "<input type='search' name='search' id='searc-basic' value='' placeholder='Under Construction ...' disabled='disabled' data-mini='true' data-theme='c' />"+
      "<a rel='close' data-role='button' style='color:white' href='#' data-theme='b'>Cancel</a>"
      });
    }); 
});
$("div[data-role='page']").live("pageshow",function(){
    console.log($("link[href$='styleDay.css']").length);
    if ($("link[href$='styleDay.css']").length > 0){
        $("#day").attr("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
        $("#night").removeAttr("checked").checkboxradio("refresh");
    }
    $("input[name='radio-choice-1']").on('change mousedown',function(event) {
           $("link").attr("href",$("input[checked][name='radio-choice-1']").val());
     });
});
```

Comment: fyi, this is happening when I'm transitioning between pages.

Comment: You should post your code starting from the global scope so we can offer advise as to how to implement your code better.

Comment: Appreciate your willingness to help, Jasper, sorry I'm a Stackoverflow newbie and have only been looking out for Answers while neglecting to check this Comments section.  I'll work on scrubbing my code of private/proprietary stuff and post it soon.